# Hibernate Lazy init exception in spring scheduled job

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring scheduled job (`@Scheduled`) that sends emails from my system according to a list of recipients in the DB.

This method is annotated with the `@Scheduled` annotation and it invokes a method from another interface, the method in the interface is annotated with the `@Transactional` annotation.

Now, when i invoke the scheduled method manually, it works perfectly. But when the method is invoked by spring scheduler i get the LazyInitFailed exception in the method implementing the said interface.

What am I doing wrong?

code:

The scheduled method:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledReportsSender {

    public static final int MAX_RETIRES = 3;
    public static final long HALF_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 30; 

    @Autowired
    IScheduledReportDAO scheduledReportDAO;

    @Autowired
    IDataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    IErrorService errorService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 ? * *") // every day at 2:10AM
    public void runDailyReports() {
        // get all daily reports
        List<ScheduledReport> scheduledReports = scheduledReportDAO.getDaily();
        sendScheduledReports(scheduledReports);
    }

    private void sendScheduledReports(List<ScheduledReport> scheduledReports) {
        if(scheduledReports.size()<1) {
            return;
        }
        //check if data flow ended its process by checking the report_last_updated table in dwh
        int reportTimeId = scheduledReportDAO.getReportTimeId();
        String todayTimeId = DateUtils.getTimeid(DateUtils.getTodayDate());
        int yesterdayTimeId = Integer.parseInt(DateUtils.addDaysSafe(todayTimeId, -1));
        int counter = 0;

        //wait for time id to update from the daily flow
        while (reportTimeId != yesterdayTimeId && counter < MAX_RETIRES) {
            errorService.logException("Daily report sender, data not ready. Will try again in one hour.", null, null, null);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(HALF_HOUR);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            reportTimeId = scheduledReportDAO.getReportTimeId();
            counter++;
        }

        if (counter == MAX_RETIRES) {
            MarketplaceServiceException mse = new MarketplaceServiceException();
            mse.setMessage("Data flow not done for today, reports are not sent.");
            throw mse;
        }

        // get updated timeid
        updateTimeId();

        for (ScheduledReport scheduledReport : scheduledReports) {
            dataService.generateScheduledReport(scheduledReport);
        }
    }

}
```

The Invoked interface:

```
public interface IDataService {

    @Transactional
    public void generateScheduledReport(ScheduledReport scheduledReport);
}
```

The implementation (up to the line of the exception):

```
@Service
public class DataService implements IDataService {

public void generateScheduledReport(ScheduledReport scheduledReport) {

        // if no recipients or no export type - return
        if(scheduledReport.getRecipients()==null || scheduledReport.getRecipients().size()==0 || scheduledReport.getExportType() == null) {
            return;
        }
}
}
```

Stack trace:

```
ERROR: 2012-09-01 03:30:00,365 [Scheduler-15] LazyInitializationException.<init>(42) | failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.x.model.scheduledReports.ScheduledReport.recipients, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.x.model.scheduledReports.ScheduledReport.recipients, no session or session was closed
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:248)
        at com.x.service.DataService.generateScheduledReport(DataService.java:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy208.generateScheduledReport(Unknown Source)
        at com.x.scheduledJobs.ScheduledReportsSender.sendScheduledReports(ScheduledReportsSender.java:85)
        at com.x.scheduledJobs.ScheduledReportsSender.runDailyReports(ScheduledReportsSender.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
ERROR: 2012-09-01 03:30:00,366 [Scheduler-15] MethodInvokingRunnable.run(68) | Invocation of method 'runDailyReports' on target class [class com.x.scheduledJobs.ScheduledReportsSender] failed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.x.model.scheduledReports.ScheduledReport.recipients, no session or session was closed
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:248)
        at com.x.service.DataService.generateScheduledReport(DataService.java:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy208.generateScheduledReport(Unknown Source)
        at com.x.scheduledJobs.ScheduledReportsSender.sendScheduledReports(ScheduledReportsSender.java:85)
        at com.x.scheduledJobs.ScheduledReportsSender.runDailyReports(ScheduledReportsSender.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

getReportTimeid implementation:

```
@Override
    public int getReportTimeId() {
        Query query = super.entityManager.createNativeQuery("select timeid from lgdwh.report_last_updated order by timeid desc limit 1");
        return (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the necessary code and stack trace?

Comment: Hi James, edited question with code.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the problem lies in the loading of the collection of recipients for each ScheduledReport. Can you post the code for this class too?

Comment: Hi James, Thank you for your time, I think the problem is that i select the scheduledReport collection outside the transaction and then try to init a collection inside the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was extracting an object from the DB in the scheduled class and passing it to a class that does work on the object, my solution was to initialize the object in the scheduled class before passing it to the class that does the work.

Comment: Did you try adding `@Transactional` to `runDailyReports`?

Comment: @Paujo Yes, it works if I do but the query to get the `reportTimeId` does not refresh if the database was updated.

Comment: @Paujo, added to the question body.

Comment: Updating reportTimeId happens inside updateTimeId()? That would mean it happens in the transaction.